# Interface Builder - How to create a custom UIView with many subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

How can I create a custom UIView (with many subviews, UITextFields etc) in interface builder?

I don't want a viewController with NIB just a simple UIView, with lots of subviews, created in IB that I can then just alloc init and use, is this possible?

Comment: If you are using interface builder is going to have a NIB. . .

Comment: It's not that I don't want a NIB, I just want to create a UIVIEW with interface builder, a standalone uiview, how can I do that?

Comment: What if you create it with interface builder then delete the view controller manually  ?

Comment: Ok, how do I alloc init from the NIB?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can create a UIView in a nib -- when you create a view based nib, that's what you're creating, a UIView. There is no view controller (though often, you make a view controller the File's Owner of the nib).

You would need to create a custom view class, and change the class of the view on the xib to that custom class, to hookup IBOutlets in that view. When you want to use the view in a controller, you can instantiate it like this:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
CustomView *view = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The limitation of this method, is that your outlets belong to the view class and not the view controller, which may not (but could be) be the right thing to do in a MVC sense.

Comment: @JohnWoods, if you want the view controller to have properties that point to the UI elements in the view (instead of IBOutlets to the view), you can do it by giving each view a unique tag, and use viewWithTag: to find them, and assign them to a property. In that case, you wouldn't need to create a custom class, since you wouldn't be using IBOutlets.

Comment: thanks really good information I created new UiView Class and xib file and I called inside of uiviewController that seem on this viewController :)