# how do i create a custom uiview from a xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I worked on a project recently where the senior engineer created a custom tab bar. He completely removed the traditional tab bar and replaced it with his own. Looking at the code, I can see that he created the files HOFooterBar.h, HOFooterBar.m, and HOFooterBar.xib. Within the .xib file, he drew out what the footer is supposed to look like in interface builder. He inherited the UIView class. Within the .h file, he created a protocol for the class, so that commands can be taken from actions given within the view. On the main view controller, he simply added a UIView where it belonged, and changed the class to HOFooterBar in the identity inspector.

That's what I can see, but I'm trying to reproduce the results in my own code and it's not working. The UIView i add to my view controller just shows up white. At one point, I added the UIView to my code manually (without IB) and it worked. But i need to be able to add it from interface builder. Any ideas how to make this happen, and why it isn't working for me? I'm open to more questions if i wasnt clear enough

Comment: Did you do this [self.view addSubview:yourButton]; ?

Comment: no, i was hoping to do everything from interface builder. i didnt expect to have to add it to the subview programmatically. typically, in IB, you dont have to do that line if you added the button from the code. if i DO do that, it works. but i wanted to change the view in identity inspector and have it display afterward

Comment: Are you loading your view from a nib? I would do something like `yourTabBar = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourTabBar" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];` and then `self.view addSubview:yourTabBar]`

Comment: if i do that, it works. but i want to be able to change the uiview in identity inspector and have it load instead of loading it programmatically like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So once you have your custom view written (make sure it inherits from `UIView`)
You can go to your main xib, and on the bottom right make sure you have the object selected (cube thing), and search for custom view.  From there, you can drag that custom view into your main view-- and then in the identity inspector assign that custom view to be an instance of your custom view class.

If the contents of the custom view are being created programmatically (which is what it sounds like your senior engineer friend did in his header/implementation files), then the custom view will show up being empty in your xib, and during runtime the custom view will populate with what was given to it programmatically.

Comment: hopefully I understood your question correctly, let me know if I got something wrong

Comment: so i tried to drag a UIView object over to IB, clicked on it, went to identity inspector, and changed the name to the name of my tab bar. When i do that, it shows up blank. However, if i get in my code and write footer = [PAFooterBar alloc] init]; [self.view addSubview:footer]; then it works. i wanted it to work without having to change the code at all. just drag the view, change the name in identity inspector, and be done with it. is it possible?

Comment: Hmm... try going to the connections inspector, and setting the referencing outlet to be your 'self' AKA the parent view?

Answer (score 3):

To create view with .xib we can use following steps

1. Create custom UIView subclass
2. Create custom.xib and set custom class from identity inspector
3. Create custom view instance as follows

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomView" bundle:nil];
YourCustomView *view = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

4. Add view to its supper view using

```
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109741/interface-builder-how-to-create-a-custom-uiview-with-many-subviews) is same reference question